# Put graphics on the screen without /dev/fb0

Tags: linux, graphics, framebuffer

I am trying to draw things on the screen without an X11 server. (I want my program to be in initrd, so I don't want to bloat it with X11.)

It's easy when I have `/dev/fb0`, but when I use Xen, I don't have it (also I am not sure how that works - the passing of vesafb to the kernel by grub and such).

I've tried SDL but it won't work without `/dev/fb0` or X11. **How does X11 work without /dev/fb0?** It seems like no matter what I do X11 will always work... yet all libraries (like directfb, SDL, etc.) will fail.

Comment: Thank you for editing my question. I hope I can get an answer from someone. I will now test and record the X11's log and some other logs in the following cases:
1. Default VGA driver
2. Nvidia bumblebee(I am using a laptop with Optimus card)
3. Xen with default driver
4. Xen with bumblebee
Hope I can get some idea how it's done from the logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the /dev/fb0 handeling with kernel. you must enable:

- CONFIG_FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE if you want to enable 'df' for console
- CONFIG_DRM and VGA card driver in this.
- FB and your VGA card driver in this.

Comment: I am not sure. in theory Xen not effect to VM functionality at all.